# Where to start when I'm the solo product designer in the company?

Tags: user-research, ux-field, ux-designer, product-design, branding

to rephrase my question from earlier. In my current job, we don't have specific colors, font styles or grid to use yet and we didn't agree on a budget for rebranding yet as we will hire a design to do that. Is it ok to redesign the website components before we finish the rebranding?

Comment: Hi Fatma, thanks for your contribution to UXSE :) I think you need to weigh up a few different issues to prioritize the work, and since you are the only person in the startup, how you come up with the decision depends on what your job description is, what your budget is, product development timeline and a bunch of other details that you probably need to provide if you want a better response from the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am also in a similar position. I am about to start my internship with a  startup. Their only product is an app but I will be playing around with data. I am planning to start it this way, as the major chunk of the application needs a UX and UI overhaul.

I would start with an expert evaluation/ heuristic evaluation. There is no competitor product, so I am canceling out the competitive analysis part. The next phase will be research, then design, followed by usability testing and launch.

I would like to hear the opinion from the community and see if this could be a good direction.

Comment: +1 Sounds sensible based on your particular situation, but I guess to answer the original questions we would probably need to know more about the company and their products/services and anything else that will help weigh up priorities.